# custom directive to add ng-click then draw input element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this directive returning the followings :

what I am trying to do here is :

1- add click event .

2-this click will draw an input field ,

so far , the ng-click is being added to DOM but it doesn't call the add function,
as you can see I tried to use compile but the whole element is gone when I used it

what am I doing wrong ?

```
return { 
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      $scope.add = add;
      $scope.remove = remove;
      el = element.attr('ng-click', 'add()');
      // $compile(el);

    function add(){
        console.log("inside addinput<<<<<<")
        var element =  '<div>\
            <input type="text"/>\
            <button ng-click="remove()">Save</button>\
            <button ng-click="remove()">Close</button>\
            </div>';
        newElement = $compile(newElement)($scope);
        element.append(newElement)
      }
      function remove(){
        newElement.remove();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work :

```
 el = element.attr('ng-click', 'add()');
```

(you could use the compile function for this. It's just that the link function is a too-late phase to do that)

You should do this instead :

```
   el .on('click', add);
```

Also you should move the implementation of `add` to a controller ( or a scope)

Comment: Okay you are correct :) @Royi I added a controller to that directive it worked , just a little comment you meant element.on('click', $scope.add) not add , also what about the remove ? now its not working do you have comments about it ?

Comment: Actually you can use both places , but controller should be the place http://plnkr.co/edit/lekbrXKbMuj7GYwPBNTa?p=info

Comment: got your point , say I want to pass the $event with the click , to do $event.preventDefault() , how can I implement that ?